# Anyway to use an external diff editor in Eclipse with EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, compare, external, egit

Is there anyway to configure Eclipse/EGit to use an external diff editor and merge tool when doing differences/merges?  I've been looking for a way to use something like BeyondCompare or DiffMerge or Kaleidoscope, but so far haven't found anyway to configure it.

I realize that BC has their own plugin, but it does not work within Egit context (ie: when looking at history and comparing to working tree, etc).

I'm running Eclipse 3.7SR2 (Indigo) and eGit 2.1.0.  I've tried putting stuff in my .gitconfig to use external diff tools, but Eclipse still opens the files in its own compare windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not supported by EGit, see [bug 356832](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356832) which tracks this enhancement and also includes a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Do you understand the workaround?  I do not understand what the "external tools" menu means/refers to.  I do not have the ability to configure any external tool to launch git when looking at a history log/etc.

Comment: See [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm). In the bug report, the user configured it for running `git mergetool` in case of conflict. This only works for an external merge tool, but not for external diff tools, because there is not yet a way to pass the selected commits to the external program.

Comment: Ok - thanks.  Had not realized that, which would explain why I was having trouble understanding how to get it to work.

Comment: I created [bug 415475](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415475) to track providing variables for selected commits, could also be useful for other things.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try the eclipse plugin "External Compare" (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/externalcompare). This plugin opens the contents of the internal eclipse editor in an external editor.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with EGit. Tried with Eclipse 4.7.1 and WinMerge on Win7

Answer (score 0):

You can use kdiff3 for GIT merging and diffing in Eclipse:

Follow these steps to set up kdiff3 to merge git conflicts within eclipse :

1. Let git create a config file

- can be **skipped** if there is **already** a **.gitconfig file in your userdir**.

  Windows users:

  %userprofile%  (copy paste in Explorer adress bar)
- a file named ".gitconfig" needs to exist there

1.1 open a cmd window, execute:

```
git config --global --edit
```

- The config file was created.

2. Open the **config file ".gitconfig"**
   2.1 add the following lines to register kdiff3 as the diff and merge tool for git (customize the paths to you needs):

   [difftool "kdiff3"]
   path = "C:\Program Files\KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
   #

   [mergetool "kdiff3"]
   path = "C:\Program Files\KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
   #trustExitCode = true
   #

Note: This would be the location to register any other supprted mergetool of your liking.

3. Create a new  "Program" "External Tools Configuration" named "git merge" to execute merges from within eclipse!
   3.1 Select the following for the parameters:

- Location:

  C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
- Working directory:

  ${git_work_tree}
- Arguments:

  mergetool --tool=kdiff3

To execute a merge, use the **standard eclipse merge** and as soon as the **workspace shows the conflicted state** (red markers on projects visible) you **mark a project you wish to merge and start the "external tools configuration"** we created in the steps listed above.

The **merge will start and the kdiff3 window will pop up.**
from now just go along your business and only save the files when you are happy with the merge result, as kdiff will deliver a positive merge feedback if you have saved the file.